# R programming Sapply function

Tags: r

I am trying to create a matrix with 100 rows and 20 columns using sapply function and I want to fill the matrix with random variables of values between 0 and 1

Comment: Can you show us your current try?

Comment: sapply(100:20,rtriangle)                                               The reason i chose rtriangle is I want to generate the numbers from 0 to 1 and the first one 100:20 is 100 rows and 20 columns

Comment: Sorry, that makes little sense. 100:20 creates the vector (100, 99, 98, ..., 21, 20) and not a 20 x 100 matrix. See my answer below

Comment: I guess I haven't asked my question correctly I am looking to generate a matrix with random numbers from 0 to 1 in a 100 row 20 column matrix  and How do i do it by using sapply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

```
replicate(20, rtriangle(100))
sapply(rep(100, 20), rtriangle)
```

Both will produce 100x20 matrices.

Answer (score 0):

sapply() iterates over one-dimensional structures such as vectors or lists. If possible, the returned results are eventually combined into a matrix. To create a 20 x 100 matrix, you need to run sapply() on some structure that has 100 elements for a function that returns a vector of 20 elements. Here is a simple example:

```
    sapply(1:100, function(x) x * (1:20))
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers, UBod

Comment: I still didn't get lets say if i want to generate random numbers from 0 to 1 and I want a matrix of 100 X 20

Comment: A 100x20 matrix with random numbers? Then you don't need sapply at all. The following should do it for you:

        matrix(runif(100 * 20), 100, 20)