# understanding sapply function in r

Tags: r, sapply

This might be the most stupid question, but I do not seem to grasp the function sapply: Here is my issue

```
      Example: 
      d = matrix(1:10, 5,2)
      d[3] = NA

 #              [,1] [,2]
         #[1,]    1    6
         #[2,]    2    7
         #[3,]   NA    8
         #[4,]    4    9
         #[5,]    5   10
```

If I would like to calculate the row means using sapply function I would use something like this:

```
       sapply(d,mean)
       #[1]  1  2 NA  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Should it not give me the mean of the list of the elements? It just spits out the elements of my matrix rather then the mean.

When I use apply, I get the right answer:

```
   apply(d,1,mean, na.rm=T)
   [1] 3.5 4.5 8.0 6.5 7.5
```

Can anyone bother giving me a very dummy explanation.Highly appreicated. 
Used the following links before asking the question. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789136/r-programming-sapply-function?rq=1) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849927/sapply-function-in-r) [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738757/simple-inquiry-about-using-sapply-in-r)

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477768/lapply-works-over-an-array-or-a-single-element/27477951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you read `?sapply`. The function takes either a vector or an expression object. It cannot take a matrix. So what happens in your example is that the matrix `d` is considered as a vector of numeric:

```
sapply(as.numeric(d),mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

`sapply` (and its friends, like `lapply`) require a list (or a data.frame, which is really a special kind of list) as input.  But even if you had turned your matrix into a data frame, it wouldn't have given you *row* means, it would have given you  *column* means.  If you want to understand how these functions work, it might help to look at this function (copied from here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html), which shows the essence of `lapply` using base R.  (`sapply` works in the same way, it just tries to simplify the output to a vector rather than always returning a list.)

```
lapply2 <- function(x, f, ...) {
 out <- vector("list", length(x))
 for (i in seq_along(x)) {
   out[[i]] <- f(x[[i]], ...)
  }
  out
}
```

By the way, if the point of your question is to find the best way of calculating row means, rather than understanding `sapply`, then there is a function `rowMeans` that is the fastest way of doing it -- faster than using `apply`, for example.